# python dict timing mystery

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, alignment, timing

I'm doing sequence alignment, and have run into a rather mysterious timing issue related to the origin of my dict data structure. 
Basically, I have function `alignment(s1, s2, scores)`
which takes in two string s1 and s2, and a scoring matrix (as a python dict) for each possible pair of 20 amino acids and a gap '-'. So `scores` has 440 keys (char1, char2), with integer values.

Here is the mystery: If I read `scores` from a text file (call it scores1) and run 
    `alignment(s1, s2, scores1)`
for some 1000-ish long strings s1, s2 of amino acids I get the following timing (using cProfile and not showing the function output):

`2537776 function calls in 11.796 seconds`

Now if I create the exactly same dict in my file (call it scores2) and run 
    `alignment(s1, s2, scores2)` 
I get the same output results but in 3 times less time:

`2537776 function calls in 4.263 seconds`

The output in both cases is identical, it is just the timing that is different. 
Running `print scores1 == scores2` results in `True`, so they contain identical information.
I verified that using an arbitrary function (instead of alignment) that accesses the dict 
many times yields the same factor of 3 timing discrepancy in the two cases.

There must be some metadata related to where the dicts originated from that is slowing down my function (when from a file), even though in both cases I actually read in the file. 
I tried creating a new dict object for each via `scores1 = dict(scores1)` etc., but the same timing discrepancy persists. Quite confusing, but I'm pretty sure there will be a good lesson in this if I can figure it out.

```
scores1 = create_score_dict_from_file('lcs_scores.txt')
scores2 = create_score_dict(find_alp(s1, s2), match=1, mismatch=0, indel=0)
print scores1 == scores2   # True
alignment(s1, s2, scores1) # gives right answer in about 12s
alignment(s1, s2, scores2) # gives right answer in about 4s
```

EDIT: Added code and results below:

Here is the a simplified version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

def create_scores_from_file(score_file, sigma=0):
    """
    Creates a dict of the scores for each pair in an alphabet,
    as well as each indel (an amino acid, paired with '-'), which is scored -sigma.

    """
    f = open(score_file, 'r')
    alp = f.readline().strip().split()
    scores = []
    for line in f:
        scores.append(map(int, line.strip().split()[1:]))
    f.close()
    scores = np.array(scores)
    score_dict = {}
    for c1 in range(len(alp)):
        score_dict[(alp[c1], '-')] = -sigma
        score_dict[('-', alp[c1])] = -sigma
        for c2 in range(len(alp)):
            score_dict[(alp[c1], alp[c2])] = scores[c1, c2]
    return score_dict

def score_matrix(alp=('A', 'C', 'G', 'T'), match=1, mismatch=0, indel=0):
    score_dict = {}
    for c1 in range(len(alp)):
        score_dict[(alp[c1], '-')] = indel
        score_dict[('-', alp[c1])] = indel
        for c2 in range(len(alp)):
            score_dict[(alp[c1], alp[c2])] = match if c1 == c2 else mismatch
    return score_dict

def use_dict_in_function(n, d):
    start = time()
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        for k in d.keys():
            count += d[k]
    print "Time: ", time() - start
    return count

def timing_test():
    alp = tuple('A  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  K  L  M  N  P  Q  R  S  T  V  W  Y'.split())
    scores1 = create_scores_from_file('lcs_scores.txt')
    scores2 = score_matrix(alp, match=1, mismatch=0, indel=0)
    print type(scores1), id(scores1)
    print type(scores2), id(scores2)
    print repr(scores1)
    print repr(scores2)
    print type(list(scores1)[0][0])
    print type(list(scores2)[0][0])
    print scores1 == scores2
    print repr(scores1) == repr(scores2)
    n = 10000
    use_dict_in_function(n, scores1)
    use_dict_in_function(n, scores2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    timing_test()
```

The results are:

```
<type 'dict'> 140309927965024
<type 'dict'> 140309928036128
{('S', 'W'): 0, ('G', 'G'): 1, ('E', 'M'): 0, ('P', '-'): 0,... (440 key: values)
{('S', 'W'): 0, ('G', 'G'): 1, ('E', 'M'): 0, ('P', '-'): 0,... (440 key: values)
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
True
True
Time:  1.51075315475
Time:  0.352770090103
```

Here is the contents of the file lcs_scores.txt:

```
   A  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  K  L  M  N  P  Q  R  S  T  V  W  Y
A  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
C  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
D  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
E  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
F  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
G  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
H  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
I  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
K  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
L  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
M  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
N  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
P  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
Q  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  
R  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  
S  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  
T  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  
V  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  
W  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  
Y  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Python?  And print the `repr()` of each dict to ensure they really are the same (not *just* that they compare equal).  Can't guess.  For example, perhaps you're using Python 2, and in one case your `char1` and `char2` are plain strings but in the other case they're Unicode strings.  Then comparison would say they're the same, but `repr()` will show the difference:

```
>>> d1 = {"a": 1}
>>> d2 = {u"a": 1}
>>> d1 == d2
True
>>> print repr(d1), repr(d2)
{'a': 1} {u'a': 1}
```

In any case, in CPython there is absolutely no internal "metadata" recording where *any* object came from.

**EDIT - something to try**

Wonderful job whittling down the problem!  This is becoming a pleasure :-)  I'd like you to try something.  First comment out this line:

```
    scores = np.array(scores)
```

Then change this line:

```
            score_dict[(alp[c1], alp[c2])] = scores[c1, c2]
```

to:

```
            score_dict[(alp[c1], alp[c2])] = scores[c1][c2]
                                                    ^^^^^^
```

When I do that, the two methods return essentially identical times.  I'm not a `numpy` expert, but my guess is that your "from file" code is using a machine-native `numpy` integer type for the dict values, and that there's substantial overhead to convert those into Python integers whenever the values are used.

Or maybe not - but that's my guess for now, and I'm sticking to it ;-)

Comment: Python 2.7.5

repr() gives identical results: 

`{('S', 'W'): 0, ('G', 'G'): 1, ('E', 'M'): 0, ('P', '-'): 0,...`

Comment: Does `repr(scores1) == repr(scores2)` return `True`? Don't trust your eyeballs for this ;-)

Comment: Yup. `repr(scores1) == repr(scores2)` returns True and `type(list(scores1.keys())[0][0])` return `<type 'str'>` in both cases

Comment: Then you have a Mystery Indeed - but you already knew that ;-)  I know about as much as anyone on Earth about CPython's dict implementation, and I don't have another theory.  Unless someone else chimes in with a brilliant idea, I'm afraid you'll have to post enough code so that other people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll condense it down to the essence and then post the code.

Comment: Long shot: it's *possible*, if keys are added to the dicts in a different order, that the `repr` could be the same but the internal order of collisions in the hash tables differed. That could make a difference if some keys are referenced more often than others, and the heavily referenced key(s) suffer long collision chains in one case. But I'm compounding improbabilities, and there's no way to get at the dict's internals from Python code. I suppose you could try timing access to each individual key: maybe one or two keys take much longer in `scores1` - or maybe they *all* take longer - or ...

Comment: i was headed down that path... but with only 440 keys, how many collisions would you really get anyways, in a normal python dict? unless you got really, really unlucky i guess...

Comment: I reproduced the same timing discrepancy using a generic function that just cycles through each key many times... actually it's even worse now. A factor of 4 different time.

Comment: I understood that from your original post - but grand totals don't tell us anything about the *distribution* of timings across keys. In the meantime, I looked some into the internals of keys taken as 2-tuples from the string `"GAVLIPFYWSTCMNQKRHDE-"`, and there's nothing even slightly pathological about them. "condense it down to the essence" remains the best hope :-)

Comment: OK figured it out...
Using `np.array` internally in the create_scores_from_file() function (which is totally unnecessary in my case!) converts the ints into
`<type 'numpy.int64'>`, which then gets compared with regular ints in use_dict(). The many conversions of int into numpy int64 accounts for the bad timing.

Comment: Oops! See my edit just now - I was typing up the same idea while you were typing that comment.  Problem solved :-)

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the help.
Lesson learned: Be very careful with your data types! 
And don't use mix numpy data types with built-in data types.

Comment: BTW, it's a shame that `numpy` didn't implement `repr` to *show* when one of its types is in use. Python is very careful to ensure that, e.g., `repr()` returns different strings for ints, floats, ahd complex numbers, even when they compare equal.